# "Как хорошо" or "Насколько хорошо"?

Tags: словоупотребление, наречия

[Reverso Context](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/How+well) shows them both used at roughly the same frequencies for "How well", as in

> "How well do you know [something or someone, like a language or
> subject]?"

without any subtle difference in meaning that I could see from the examples, but I could find no other info on this online, so I wanted any Russian native speakers to point out any subtle differences that mean I ought to choose one instead of the other, and which one they see more often.

Answer (score 1):

if the question defines an adverb, then there is no significant difference between the two.

*Как* literally means "how", and *насколько* literally means "how much".

In English, "how much well" is not an idiomatic way of putting it, but it is in Russian and other languages.

If the question defines a verb or an adjective rather than adverb, e.g. *насколько ты ему доверяешь?* "how much do you trust him?" or *насколько он высок* "how tall is he?", then *насколько* is the only possible option. With verbs (but not with adjectives), it's much like in English.

Comment: Thank you. With an adverb (e.g., "Как хорошо" or "Насколько хорошо"), is one more common than the other? Is there any _slight_ difference in connotation or tone or formality whatsoever?

Comment: @SUM1: if you can replace them at all, I can't think of any perceptible difference between them.